# HTML Form Submit not readable for PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, post, submit

i´ve got a little problem with my php code.
The code contains a form that reloads the document. But after the reaload I cant read the POST data. Here is the HTML code:

```
<form action="config_page.php" method="post">
  ... some Inputs
  <input type="submit" value="Save" name="config_btn" class="submitbtn_2">
</form>
```

On top of config_page.php ive got this PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST["config_btn"])){
  echo "isset";
  //Some Database writing
}else{
  echo "is not set";
}
```

Bizarrely, the output "is not set" always appears after submiting the form, but Database Changes are applied anyway... (Database Changes are only performed if the isset statement is true)

Can someone figure out the problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i can't see a error in your script. so please check the dev console ``F12`` and the network tab if your post is send successfully

Comment: Start by debugging your script. what does `var_dump($_POST);` give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POST` values will always set after post or submit form with form post method

`echo "is not set";` always true until you not click on submit or post any values. after submit click you will find `$_POST["config_btn"]` is set true so db queries runs.

so keep your form in else part.

So :-

```
if(isset($_POST["config_btn"])){
  echo "isset";
  //Some Database writing
}else{
  echo "is not set";
}
```

1. When page loaded it's goes to else condition and will `echo "is not set";`
2. When you click on submit POST values found and it's runs your query.
3. if you redirect page again then again post values will be end and goes to else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i dont get it. Logically (in my head) if i push the button, the isset part should be processed. Could you explain your comment please? Thank you!